# The non-nullable variable 'cameras' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, camera

I'm getting below error in my code when I'm trying to use cameras variable. how to correct this. appreciate your help on this.

```
The non-nullable variable 'cameras' must be initialized.
```

> CameraScreeen.dart

```
 import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    
    List <CameraDescription> cameras;
    
    class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const CameraScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
    }
    
    class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold();
      }
    }
```

main.dartt

```
Future <void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  cameras =await availableCameras();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the sound null safety feature of Flutter and Dart.

Variables cannot be null now if you want to accept them `null` values you have to make them nullable using `?`

for example:

`List <CameraDescription>? cameras;`

If you still don't want to make them nullable then you can use a `late` keyword which allows us to initialize value later on but we have to make sure that it is initialized before is being used somewhere.

for example:

`late List <CameraDescription> cameras;`

Answer (score 0):

Make the cameras variable.
like:-

```
List <CameraDescription>? cameras;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not leave a not null variable without assign dart null safety not allowing this..

Your Global variable camera is not initialized

```
List<> camera;//for global it is not acceptable

you can make List<>? camera;// now it is acceptable but you must need to initialize first before using it other wise it will throw exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the `cameras List` nullable like this:

```
List<CameraDescription>? cameras;
```

OR if you don't want to make it nullable then you can make an empty cameras list like this:

```
List<CameraDescription> cameras = List<CameraDescription>.empty(growable: true);
```